# Rearrange CSS dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I am following [a tutorial to make a css dropdown menu](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu). But I was wondering if there was a way to make this so it appears on the left side, one button on top of the other, instead of on the top, where the buttons are next to each other.

Comment: Site is having problems; google has a [cached copy](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:MoohMxfaqzgJ:line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu+) for now

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a tutorial to learn, why not just follow a tutorial for a vertical menu?  Not only is the positioning different for the items in the menu, but the positioning of the children elements are going to be much different as well.  If you are creating a horizontal menu like you are, even if you move the elements on top of each other those child elements are going to cover up other menu items if they still have the same 'drop down' when their parent is hovered/clicked.

Here's an example of a vertical menu tutorial, but there are tons out there.
http://www.devinrolsen.com/pure-css-vertical-menu/

Answer (score 2):

You will want to either remove or alter this CSS property:

```
nav ul li {
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qt3Hc/) for a vertical menu based on the link you provided. I removed all the fancy gradients, padding and rounded corners, only a little color is used, the rest is all functional CSS.

Each menu item can be the root of a submenu with this CSS:

```
nav li {
     position: relative;
}
nav ul ul {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 100%;
}
```

This way you can create menus with an arbitrary depth.